# Cause archive corruption (intentionally)

Tags: .net, windows-7, 64-bit, archive, corruption

I'm currently trying to debug some archive corruption issues that some customers are experiencing.  Our product updates via patches, and in some cases (specifically, with some Win7 64-bit users) this patching process seems to be corrupting some of the archives used by the product.  The corruption is always localized to just one file in the archive, never the entire archive.

The problem here is that I'm completely unable to reproduce the archive corruption they're experiencing.  Of course, trying to fix the source of the problem is my primary goal, but I also need to diagnose and fix the existing corruption.  However, I'm unable to come up with a decent test case.  I can easily corrupt the entire archive (just modifying with a hex editor does the trick), but not just one file within.

Any ideas on how to do this?  In this case, since the archives are so large, I cannot get users to upload their corrupted versions to me, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

If the customer has access to both clean and corrupted archives, can you ask them to produce a diff of the binary files? Then the customer only has to send the patch file which should be significantly smaller the the whole archive. 
For one possible binary diff tool see - http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/